# How would I populate an Android Spinner with data from a MySQL Database?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am required to create a Wireless-enabled Android application. My idea, is to create a ticket booking system which allows the user to select a ticket type via a Spinner. The spinner will be populated with information from a MySQL database, which will mean the application uses some sort of wireless connectivity. In addition to this I would like the cost associated with the chosen ticket type to be displayed in my application as well. The database itself currently consists of the following 3 records:

```
Adult - 24.99
Senior - 19.99
Child - 14.99
```

So I need to find a way of populating my spinner with the above data allowing the user to choose either Adult, Senior or Child. Then if it's possible, use a textview to display the associated cost depending on the ticket the user has chosen. I've done a bit of research and it looks like I'll have to use PHP to connect and retrieve the data I require, although I have absolutely no idea how I would go about doing this. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated or if anyone requires more information please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question, as I understand it, is asking how to transfer data between the PHP/MySQL server and the Android client. My answer to this question is [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

JSON offers a simple, lightweight, and human-readable way to transfer raw data. One JSON representation of your data may look like this:

```
{"Adult":24.99,"Senior":19.99,"Child":14.99}
```

On the PHP server, you can convert pretty much any variable into a JSON string using the [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) function:

```
<?php
// TODO create this array from the database
$prices = array('Adult' => 24.99, 'Senior' => 19.99, 'Child' => 14.99);

echo json_encode($prices);
?>
```

On the Android client, you can decode JSON using the [Jackson JSON Processor](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) library. The data binding mode makes it incredibly easy to convert JSON strings into Java objects. (Here I'm converting the data to a generic type `Map<String, Float>`, but you could also create a custom type like `Price.class` and use to that instead of the `new TypeReference ...` part.)

```
// TODO download this string from the server
String json = "{\"Adult\":24.99,\"Senior\":19.99,\"Child\":14.99}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Float> prices = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Float>>() {});
```